# Native binding not working for AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

**What I am trying to do:** Assign two-way binding for `Text` property on android (native) widget `AutoCompleteTextView` as illustrated in [this article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/native-views/#Native_Bindings).

**Where it's failing:** Even though, the exact same approach works for `Switch`, but it fails for both `EditText` and `AutoCompleteTextView`. I tried using `TextChanged`, `AfterTextChanged`, and `FocusChange` as events for [`UpdateSourceEventName`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.BindingExtension.UpdateSourceEventName/) in binding expression. Each failed to work. In case of `TextChanged` the value is updated in reverse because the cursor position keeps reverting to start-point, while in `FocusChange` the event doesn't seem to be triggered at all.

[image]

**Sample code to re-create issue:**

*XAML*

```
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NativeViewTest"
    xmlns:androidWidget="clr-namespace:Android.Widget;assembly=Mono.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
    xmlns:formsAndroid="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
    x:Name="_parent"
    x:Class="NativeViewTest.NativeViewTestPage">

    <StackLayout Margin="10">

        <Label TextColor="Green" Text="Switch + CheckedChange: Binding works as expected." />
        <androidWidget:Switch x:Arguments="{x:Static formsAndroid:Forms.Context}" Text="Is Switch On?"
            Checked="{Binding Path=IsSwitchOn, Source={x:Reference _parent}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceEventName=CheckedChange}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Path=IsSwitchOn, StringFormat='IsSwitchOn: {0}', Source={x:Reference _parent}" />

        <Label TextColor="Navy" Text="AutoCompleteTextView + TextChanged: Value is updated in reverse." />
        <androidWidget:AutoCompleteTextView x:Arguments="{x:Static formsAndroid:Forms.Context}"
            Text="{Binding Path=TextChangedText, Source={x:Reference _parent}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceEventName=TextChanged}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Path=TextChangedText, StringFormat='TextChangedText: {0}', Source={x:Reference _parent}" />

        <Label TextColor="Red" Text="AutoCompleteTextView + FocusChange: Value is never updated." />
        <androidWidget:AutoCompleteTextView x:Arguments="{x:Static formsAndroid:Forms.Context}"
            Text="{Binding Path=LostFocusText, Source={x:Reference _parent}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceEventName=FocusChange}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Path=LostFocusText, StringFormat='LostFocusText: {0}', Source={x:Reference _parent}" />

        <Label TextColor="Navy" Text="AutoCompleteTextView + AfterTextChanged: Same issue as text-changed" />
        <androidWidget:AutoCompleteTextView x:Arguments="{x:Static formsAndroid:Forms.Context}"
            Text="{Binding Path=AfterTextChangedText, Source={x:Reference _parent}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceEventName=AfterTextChanged}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Path=AfterTextChangedText, StringFormat='AfterTextChangedText: {0}', Source={x:Reference _parent}" />

        <Button Text="Update" />

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

*Code-behind*

```
public partial class NativeViewTestPage : ContentPage
{
    public NativeViewTestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string _afterTextChanged;
    public string AfterTextChangedText
    {
        get { return _afterTextChanged; }
        set { 
            _afterTextChanged = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AfterTextChangedText)); 
        }
    }

    string _textChangedText = "initial value";
    public string TextChangedText
    {
        get { return _textChangedText; }
        set
        {
            _textChangedText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TextChangedText));
        }
    }

    string _lostFocusText;
    public string LostFocusText
    {
        get { return _lostFocusText; }
        set
        {
            _lostFocusText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LostFocusText));
        }
    }

    bool _isSwitchOn = false;
    public bool IsSwitchOn
    {
        get { return _isSwitchOn; }
        set
        {
            _isSwitchOn = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSwitchOn));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT - 1**

I tried changing binding mode to `OneWayToSource` assuming that would fix the cursor issue - but still causes the exact same problem.

Comment: You could read this : https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58823

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had tried not setting update-source-event; but then the value never gets updated. Technically, in this case shouldn't setting update event as `FocusChange` work? But it doesn't get triggered either, and the value on VM doesn't get updated :(.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem except with the "EditText" widget, i managed to set gravity and inputtypes flags but i can't get the value on my ViewModel and have the cursor move properly. How did you manage it?

Comment: @SwodniwS: I have not been able to find a solution to this problem yet.